# function, not defined by using def

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, however I am in need of using Python for my project, I have been learning on the go. There is a point I don't understand with the piece of code below:

```
result['data'] = pool.map(image_processor, im_info)
```

So, I figured out `pool.map(somefunc,[list of params])` is akin to `parfor` of Matlab. What I don't understand is the part relating `image_processor`. I am assuming it should be a function, however it is not defined as one using def. The code is working perfectly fine and I tried to trace it with pdb and it seems to process the images as intended in batches, for caffe input. This might be a very trivial question, I just am new to Python. So what is the order of execution that image_processor just works and how can I make changes in this function (I will be passing multiple parameters, I just need to know where I can make those changes as the function is not defined using a def) Thx.

```
#Data layer for video.  Change flow_frames and RGB_frames to be the path to the flow and RGB frames.

import sys
sys.path.append('../../python')
import caffe
import io
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import time
import pdb
import glob
import pickle as pkl
import random
import h5py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import Thread
import skimage.io
import copy

flow_frames = 'flow_images/'
RGB_frames = 'frames/'
test_frames = 16 
train_frames = 16
test_buffer = 3
train_buffer = 24

def processImageCrop(im_info, transformer, flow):
  im_path = im_info[0]
  im_crop = im_info[1] 
  im_reshape = im_info[2]
  im_flip = im_info[3]
  data_in = caffe.io.load_image(im_path)
  if (data_in.shape[0] < im_reshape[0]) | (data_in.shape[1] < im_reshape[1]):
    data_in = caffe.io.resize_image(data_in, im_reshape)
  if im_flip:
    data_in = caffe.io.flip_image(data_in, 1, flow) 
    data_in = data_in[im_crop[0]:im_crop[2], im_crop[1]:im_crop[3], :] 
  processed_image = transformer.preprocess('data_in',data_in)
  return processed_image

class ImageProcessorCrop(object):
  def __init__(self, transformer, flow):
    self.transformer = transformer
    self.flow = flow
  def __call__(self, im_info):
    return processImageCrop(im_info, self.transformer, self.flow)

class sequenceGeneratorVideo(object):
  def __init__(self, buffer_size, clip_length, num_videos, video_dict, video_order):
    self.buffer_size = buffer_size
    self.clip_length = clip_length
    self.N = self.buffer_size*self.clip_length
    self.num_videos = num_videos
    self.video_dict = video_dict
    self.video_order = video_order
    self.idx = 0

  def __call__(self):
    label_r = []
    im_paths = []
    im_crop = []
    im_reshape = []  
    im_flip = []

    if self.idx + self.buffer_size >= self.num_videos:
      idx_list = range(self.idx, self.num_videos)
      idx_list.extend(range(0, self.buffer_size-(self.num_videos-self.idx)))
    else:
      idx_list = range(self.idx, self.idx+self.buffer_size)


    for i in idx_list:
      key = self.video_order[i]
      label = self.video_dict[key]['label']
      video_reshape = self.video_dict[key]['reshape']
      video_crop = self.video_dict[key]['crop']
      label_r.extend([label]*self.clip_length)

      im_reshape.extend([(video_reshape)]*self.clip_length)
      r0 = int(random.random()*(video_reshape[0] - video_crop[0]))
      r1 = int(random.random()*(video_reshape[1] - video_crop[1]))
      im_crop.extend([(r0, r1, r0+video_crop[0], r1+video_crop[1])]*self.clip_length)     
      f = random.randint(0,1)
      im_flip.extend([f]*self.clip_length)
      rand_frame = int(random.random()*(self.video_dict[key]['num_frames']-self.clip_length)+1+1)
      frames = []

      for i in range(rand_frame,rand_frame+self.clip_length):
        frames.append(self.video_dict[key]['frames'] %i)

      im_paths.extend(frames) 


    im_info = zip(im_paths,im_crop, im_reshape, im_flip)

    self.idx += self.buffer_size
    if self.idx >= self.num_videos:
      self.idx = self.idx - self.num_videos

    return label_r, im_info

def advance_batch(result, sequence_generator, image_processor, pool):

    label_r, im_info = sequence_generator()
    #tmp = image_processor(im_info[0])
    result['data'] = pool.map(image_processor, im_info)
    result['label'] = label_r
    cm = np.ones(len(label_r))
    cm[0::16] = 0
    result['clip_markers'] = cm

class BatchAdvancer():
    def __init__(self, result, sequence_generator, image_processor, pool):
      self.result = result
      self.sequence_generator = sequence_generator
      self.image_processor = image_processor
      self.pool = pool

    def __call__(self):
      return advance_batch(self.result, self.sequence_generator, self.image_processor, self.pool)

class videoRead(caffe.Layer):

  def initialize(self):
    self.train_or_test = 'test'
    self.flow = False
    self.buffer_size = test_buffer  #num videos processed per batch
    self.frames = test_frames   #length of processed clip
    self.N = self.buffer_size*self.frames
    self.idx = 0
    self.channels = 3
    self.height = 227
    self.width = 227
    self.path_to_images = RGB_frames 
    self.video_list = 'ucf101_split1_testVideos.txt' 

  def setup(self, bottom, top):
    random.seed(10)
    self.initialize()
    f = open(self.video_list, 'r')
    f_lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    video_dict = {}
    current_line = 0
    self.video_order = []
    for ix, line in enumerate(f_lines):
      video = line.split(' ')[0].split('/')[1]
      l = int(line.split(' ')[1])
      frames = glob.glob('%s%s/*.jpg' %(self.path_to_images, video))
      num_frames = len(frames)
      video_dict[video] = {}
      video_dict[video]['frames'] = frames[0].split('.')[0] + '.%04d.jpg'
      video_dict[video]['reshape'] = (240,320)
      video_dict[video]['crop'] = (227, 227)
      video_dict[video]['num_frames'] = num_frames
      video_dict[video]['label'] = l
      self.video_order.append(video) 

    self.video_dict = video_dict
    self.num_videos = len(video_dict.keys())

    #set up data transformer
    shape = (self.N, self.channels, self.height, self.width)

    self.transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data_in': shape})
    self.transformer.set_raw_scale('data_in', 255)
    if self.flow:
      image_mean = [128, 128, 128]
      self.transformer.set_is_flow('data_in', True)
    else:
      image_mean = [103.939, 116.779, 128.68]
      self.transformer.set_is_flow('data_in', False)
    channel_mean = np.zeros((3,227,227))
    for channel_index, mean_val in enumerate(image_mean):
      channel_mean[channel_index, ...] = mean_val
    self.transformer.set_mean('data_in', channel_mean)
    self.transformer.set_channel_swap('data_in', (2, 1, 0))
    self.transformer.set_transpose('data_in', (2, 0, 1))

    self.thread_result = {}
    self.thread = None
    pool_size = 24

    self.image_processor = ImageProcessorCrop(self.transformer, self.flow)
    self.sequence_generator = sequenceGeneratorVideo(self.buffer_size, self.frames, self.num_videos, self.video_dict, self.video_order)

    self.pool = Pool(processes=pool_size)
    self.batch_advancer = BatchAdvancer(self.thread_result, self.sequence_generator, self.image_processor, self.pool)
    self.dispatch_worker()
    self.top_names = ['data', 'label','clip_markers']
    print 'Outputs:', self.top_names
    if len(top) != len(self.top_names):
      raise Exception('Incorrect number of outputs (expected %d, got %d)' %
                      (len(self.top_names), len(top)))
    self.join_worker()
    for top_index, name in enumerate(self.top_names):
      if name == 'data':
        shape = (self.N, self.channels, self.height, self.width)
      elif name == 'label':
        shape = (self.N,)
      elif name == 'clip_markers':
        shape = (self.N,)
      top[top_index].reshape(*shape)

  def reshape(self, bottom, top):
    pass

  def forward(self, bottom, top):

    if self.thread is not None:
      self.join_worker() 

    #rearrange the data: The LSTM takes inputs as [video0_frame0, video1_frame0,...] but the data is currently arranged as [video0_frame0, video0_frame1, ...]
    new_result_data = [None]*len(self.thread_result['data']) 
    new_result_label = [None]*len(self.thread_result['label']) 
    new_result_cm = [None]*len(self.thread_result['clip_markers'])
    for i in range(self.frames):
      for ii in range(self.buffer_size):
        old_idx = ii*self.frames + i
        new_idx = i*self.buffer_size + ii
        new_result_data[new_idx] = self.thread_result['data'][old_idx]
        new_result_label[new_idx] = self.thread_result['label'][old_idx]
        new_result_cm[new_idx] = self.thread_result['clip_markers'][old_idx]

    for top_index, name in zip(range(len(top)), self.top_names):
      if name == 'data':
        for i in range(self.N):
          top[top_index].data[i, ...] = new_result_data[i] 
      elif name == 'label':
        top[top_index].data[...] = new_result_label
      elif name == 'clip_markers':
        top[top_index].data[...] = new_result_cm

    self.dispatch_worker()

  def dispatch_worker(self):
    assert self.thread is None
    self.thread = Thread(target=self.batch_advancer)
    self.thread.start()

  def join_worker(self):
    assert self.thread is not None
    self.thread.join()
    self.thread = None

  def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    pass

class videoReadTrain_flow(videoRead):

  def initialize(self):
    self.train_or_test = 'train'
    self.flow = True
    self.buffer_size = train_buffer  #num videos processed per batch
    self.frames = train_frames   #length of processed clip
    self.N = self.buffer_size*self.frames
    self.idx = 0
    self.channels = 3
    self.height = 227
    self.width = 227
    self.path_to_images = flow_frames 
    self.video_list = 'ucf101_split1_trainVideos.txt' 

class videoReadTest_flow(videoRead):

  def initialize(self):
    self.train_or_test = 'test'
    self.flow = True
    self.buffer_size = test_buffer  #num videos processed per batch
    self.frames = test_frames   #length of processed clip
    self.N = self.buffer_size*self.frames
    self.idx = 0
    self.channels = 3
    self.height = 227
    self.width = 227
    self.path_to_images = flow_frames 
    self.video_list = 'ucf101_split1_testVideos.txt' 

class videoReadTrain_RGB(videoRead):

  def initialize(self):
    self.train_or_test = 'train'
    self.flow = False
    self.buffer_size = train_buffer  #num videos processed per batch
    self.frames = train_frames   #length of processed clip
    self.N = self.buffer_size*self.frames
    self.idx = 0
    self.channels = 3
    self.height = 227
    self.width = 227
    self.path_to_images = RGB_frames 
    self.video_list = 'ucf101_split1_trainVideos.txt' 

class videoReadTest_RGB(videoRead):

  def initialize(self):
    self.train_or_test = 'test'
    self.flow = False
    self.buffer_size = test_buffer  #num videos processed per batch
    self.frames = test_frames   #length of processed clip
    self.N = self.buffer_size*self.frames
    self.idx = 0
    self.channels = 3
    self.height = 227
    self.width = 227
    self.path_to_images = RGB_frames 
    self.video_list = 'ucf101_split1_testVideos.txt'
```

The code is from https://github.com/LisaAnne/lisa-caffe-public/blob/lstm_video_deploy/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/sequence_input_layer.py

Comment: Does the code really have `***` around it like that? I don't think that's valid Python syntax. If you meant it as highlighting, that doesn't work in StackOverflow code blocks

Comment: I have marked all occurrences of it in the code below with *** (intended to highlight/bold but it didn't work in code environment).

Comment: Use syntactically valid comments when you want to denote something in your code. Code samples need to be runnable so someone else can see the same error.

Comment: Also, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, code samples should be the **smallest possible runnable code** that demonstrates the same issue.

Comment: Edited. It is not a specific issue, I can not see the order of execution or where the function is defined, so I have used the script as a whole but referred to the line where it is called as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line:

```
self.image_processor = ImageProcessorCrop(self.transformer, self.flow)
```

The `ImageProcessorCrop` class has a `__call__` method, which allows these objects to be used as if they're functions. When you call them, it calls that method.